# Use color Material while in Edit / Wire Mode

Tags: interface, color

I'm using topology for face modeling. I am following a face pattern used in Blender in the Sintel character. **I'd like to see colored faces WHILE I am placing vertices and mapping out the face IN EDIT & WIRE MODE.**

This is a screen shot of what I am working on. I am following a pattern and would like to map the colors on to what I've explained above in EDIT MODE. The orange is what I have selected to group-vertex as red regions of the face topology, which I'd like to see as light red in edit mode and not in solid mode which is what I've accomplished with some help.

[image: What I'm working on]

**Intended Wish List**: Done in PhotoShop as what I want to see while editing
[image: What I would like to see in edit mode]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are facing, and then maybe a tweaked image from Gimp/Photoshop to help others visualize what you are describing?

Comment: Okay, I'll Edit with a screen shot.

Comment: The second Image I painted the desired result on the lower left. Upper left is a material view (nice to see, but you have to paint the surface and it shows in rendering). The lower left is what I am wanting to find in Blender, to see a color scheme, for mapping topology (I colored this part of the image in PhotoShop for demonstration). The Middle is a movie clip of Sintel, a topology tutorial. The right side of the image is The standard wire frame with default gray (no color).

Comment: @laughingCat as a side note: please don't follow CGcookie topology maps, they are actually not that good and have many mistakes. Especially the nose area is very bad in this example. Google some face typologies and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vertex Paint for this task.

1. Enter Edit mode, select face edgeloops which you'd like to be the same color.
2. Switch to Vertex Paint mode and enable *Face selection masking for painting* option in 3D View header to [paint only on selected vertices which form faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/is-it-possible-to-paint-only-on-selected-vertices-in-vertex-paint). Faces which were selected in Edit mode will become slightly different from others of the mesh, showing that they are selected.
3. Paint with any brush radius because the accuracy is not important any more. Rotate viewport in order to paint from different angles. Change colors for different edge loops as desired.

   [image: Vertex painting with face masking]
4. Now when in Edit or Object mode turn on *Textured Solid* in <kbd>N</kbd> panel > *Shading* scroll. In Solid or Texture viewport shading the edgeloops will be shown painted.

   [image: Vertex paint visible in Edit mode]

   *Note: this works only for Blender Internal. For Cycles you probably should bake colors to image and use it as a texture in order they to be seen in Edit mode.*

Answer (score 0):

If what I'm gathering from your question is correct.
From what I can tell, you can essentially get the same effect by just setting your Viewport shading mode to Texture, and then disable "Limit Selection to Visible".

[image]

---

**OR**

You can just UV unwrap and use any image, such as one that you posted. The difference being is that you would set the render mode to Material, and create a texture linked to the material that affects color. You could always check/uncheck the color options on the material when doing the topo work.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if that's quite it, or maybe if that's all there is. Let me give it a try and I'll let you know if that works for what I'm trying to achieve. I've posted an edit of what I'm trying to accomplish with a screen shot.

Comment: I think I might be getting somewhere. I painted a whole area blue, but I want to take it off. How do I remove material from only certain faces?

Comment: I added a second image. The lower left, you can see a shade of color in the wire mode (Which I painted on in PhotoShop). I'm suspecting this isn't an option on Blender.