# How to use 'Set Vertex Colors' properly?

Tags: vertex-paint

I'm trying to set vertex colors per faces. I already did it successfully, but obviously now I'm missing something and after numerous trials, I give up.

I use this procedure:

- Select a face in Edit mode
- Switch to Vertex Paint mode
- Select a color and execute 'Set Vertex Colors' from Header menu.

Instead of changing the color of the selected face, all faces are recolored.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Done with Blender 2.79 (and both Blender Render and Cycles).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/is-it-possible-to-paint-only-on-selected-vertices-in-vertex-paint

Comment: In your Properties > Material > Options, have you enable Vertex Color Paint option? Otherwise you can't see the result in Solid mode, only in Texture mode.

Comment: @TryingGuest: Thanks, it was the problem. I guess the question can be closed as duplicate. [I did it here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114820/15265), but didn't appreciate the use of this button at full extent.

Comment: @moonboots: The option was selected, but you're right to mention it, it can be forgotten easily.